# ng test throw error No Toaster Containers have been initialized to receive toasts

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I am using karma and jasmine. Below is the function that I want to test using spyOn.

```
getCaSyncStatus() {
service.getBenefitsCaSyncStatus()
.pipe(
  catchError((err : HttpErrorResponse) => {
    return throwError(err);
  })
)
.subscribe(res => {
}, err => {

  if(err && (err.status === 503 || err.status === 0)) {
    this.toaster.pop('error', 'API is not available');
    this.someValue = 'xxx';
  } else if(err.status === 500 ) {
    this.toaster.pop('error', 'API is not available, Contact Support');
    this.msg = 'API is down';
  }
  else {
    this.someValue = 'yyy';
  }
});
```

}

so if I throw status code using `spyOn` like this

```
 spyOn(dashboardService, "getBenefitsCaSyncStatus").and.returnValue(Observable.throw({ status: 500 }));
 component.getCaSyncStatus();
 fixture.detectChanges();
 tick();
```

It throws error "No Toaster Containers have been initialized to receive toasts". Although I have `<toaster-container></toaster-container>` in my root component.

Comment: Mock out the toaster instead of using the actual library. Set the `toaster` on the component to a jasmine mock.

Comment: @bc1105 how can I mock the toaster library?

Comment: As a proof of concept, try mocking the toaster integration on the component:
`this.component.toaster = { pop: jasmine.createSpy() }` before you call `fixture.detectChanges()`

If you inject the toaster through a service, you may mock it using `TestBed`.

Comment: It says Type '{ pop: Spy; }' is not assignable to type 'ToasterService'.
  Property 'addToast' is missing in type '{ pop: Spy; }'.

Comment: `this.component.toaster = { pop: jasmine.createSpy() } as any`

Comment: this.component.toaster. pop = jasmine.createSpy(); it works. I just need as spyOn on pop.